# How to add Recent Quick link in Communication site Modern page

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I need to add Recent Quick link in Communication site Modern Page, is there any option availabale for that?

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: Do you want to add **Recent** link in site navigation? OR on any particular site page?

Comment: In Site Navigation of communication site

Comment: Currently there is no OOB way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Add a [highlighted content web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-highlighted-content-web-part-e34199b0-ff1a-47fb-8f4d-dbcaed329efd?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) then select the content you want to highlighted:

[image]